# Have there ever been significant events of ecological or geological disasters occurring simultaneously alongside extreme meterological disasters?

Tags: natural-disasters, extreme-weather

e.g.

- A major earthquake hitting an area over which a large tropical cyclone is passing by (Haiti, Mexico (either coast), Taiwan/Japan/Philippines)
- Major tornado outbreak hitting an area inundated by wildfires (southeastern U.S. in November-December)

The text in brackets represents areas where I think such scenarios *could* happen.

Comment: Well, your two examples just answered your own question... so...

Comment: I'm only guessing. I am not aware of actual occurrences.

Comment: Is a wildfire really a geological event? If so flooding would be a geological event which would be very easy to pair with a meteorological event.

Comment: @spillthrill maybe you should add that to your post :)

Comment: Best I can muster up immediately is the Mexican earthquake this past year happening the same day as Hurricane Maria hit Puerto Rico.  But we're still talking ~2000 miles apart.  The thing is true "disasters" are quite rare occurrences... so to see two different unrelated kinds overlap is a big numerical challenge.

Comment: Think wildfires and tornado outbreaks tend to be poorly correlated because tornadoes require high moisture amounts, and regions with drought/fires tend not to have it.

Comment: See also [Can large (and wet) storms really trigger large magnitude Earthquakes?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/560/6031)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an amazing one:

In June 1991 [category 3 Typhoon Yunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoon_Yunya_(1991)) made landfall in central Luzon in the Philippines and gradually weakened as it moved across the island... however as it was near exiting the island... Mount Pinatubo sustained the [largest volcanic eruption in our lifetimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_volcanic_eruptions_of_the_20th_century) -- almost directly in the center of the storm!

**[Here is a remarkable satellite loop](http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/goes/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/19910612-16_gms4_infrared_Pinatubo_anim.gif)** showing the event unfold.

[image]
<sup><sub>Screen cap shortly before the event unfolder showing the locations, from [UW CIMSS](http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/)</sub></sup>

The [CIMSS Satellite Blog has a nice post writing up the event](http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/goes/blog/archives/21415), along with a collection of additional satellite data.

Comment: Wow! Amazing image loop indeed!

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

Here's a list of common disasters that associate with each other:

- A twister (tornado) that fused with a wildfire *(aka: a firenado)*
- A cyclone (Hurricane) that caused a tsunami *(common)*
- An earthquake in the ocean that caused a tsunami *(common)*

...and probably several more. But many times such an occurrence is typical, and often happen; such as oceanic earthquakes and hurricanes causing tsunamis; However, some of them are less likely to happen; such as the 'firenado'.

**A great example of a scenario you're asking to see is [Hurricane Sandy](https://www.cnn.com/2013/07/13/world/americas/hurricane-sandy-fast-facts/index.html)'s effects on North America.**

Sandy was known to be one of the worst hurricanes ever recorded; damagewise, costwise, and wave height *(what you wanted to hear :D)*. It has been recorded on CNN (the link added goes to the CNN article on Sandy) that its wave heights reached **32.5 feet (roughly 9.9 meters) in height.**

So in conclusion; occurrences like this happen, and some of them are typically known to occur in some the circumstances listed above.

*(Information on Hurricane Sandy was grabbed from CNN)*

*(Information on the scenarios listed above were grabbed from google)*

Comment: How does this answer the question?  What geological event occurred alongside a meteorological disaster?

Comment: Sandy was a meteorological disaster; Sandy's tsunami waves are geological disasters.

Comment: That's a pretty loose definition of geological disaster.

Comment: :( I provided a good answer, and I can never seem to get positive feedback.

Comment: @Imtherealsanic you're doing ok - you will get there in time and your answers will become better! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I think after I finish university, I'll be better at answering questions correctly :)

Comment: @Imtherealsanic even before that. I didn't finish university yet...

Comment: This a science site so your Q&A need to be science-focused and adhere to true definitions, not word play.

Comment: @farrenthorpe do you have any _positive_ things to say about my post?

Comment: I apologize... I thought you were the person who asked the question and then answered your own question.  In general I think it's a poorly constructed question. I think it's great you are keeping active.  +1 for that.

Comment: If you are looking to score points on this site, you might try constructing some interesting questions about phenomena or events that happened.  Try to keep it succinct and show some effort on starting to answer your own question.  For instance, I've asked questions about including the solar eclipse in weather models, quantifying the flooding in California, international transport of air pollutants, etc.  If it's interesting, people will upvote!

Comment: @farrenthorpe thank you for the advice. I'll take it into consideration :)

Comment: See also [Can large (and wet) storms really trigger large magnitude Earthquakes?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/560/6031)